# How to save VBA Excel code in MS Office Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I had a VBA code for excel. I wrote the code and saved and exited the file. When I opened it once again the code was missing and it wasn't saved but I remember I had saved the code.

Comment: Did you save the file as `.xlsm` ? (Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook)

Comment: No, I saved in excel format itself

Comment: I use copy/ paste and keep a copy in a text (or word) file as a backup, sorry I understand your pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wont work as the file was not saved as xlsm, you will have to do it again.

Comment: `.xlsb` is also a valid save format for Excel files containing macros.